# How to write JDBC Sink for Spark Structured Streaming [SparkException: Task not serializable]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I need a JDBC sink for my spark structured streaming data frame. At the moment, as far as I know DataFrame’s API lacks `writeStream` to JDBC implementation (neither in PySpark nor in Scala (current Spark version 2.2.0)). The only suggestion I found was to write my own `ForeachWriter` Scala class based on [this article](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/04/04/real-time-end-to-end-integration-with-apache-kafka-in-apache-sparks-structured-streaming.html).

So, I've modified a simple word count example from [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html) by adding a custom `ForeachWriter`class and tried to `writeStream` to PostgreSQL. Stream of words is generated manually from console (using NetCat: nc -lk -p 9999) and read by Spark from socket.

Unfortunately, I'm getting "Task not serializable" ERROR.

APACHE_SPARK_VERSION=2.1.0
Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_112)

My Scala code:

```scala
//Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1501242382770).
//Spark session available as 'spark'.

import java.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .master("local[*]")
  .appName("StructuredNetworkWordCountToJDBC")
  .config("spark.jars", "/tmp/data/postgresql-42.1.1.jar")
  .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

val lines = spark.readStream
  .format("socket")
  .option("host", "localhost")
  .option("port", 9999)
  .load()

val words = lines.as[String].flatMap(_.split(" "))

val wordCounts = words.groupBy("value").count()

class JDBCSink(url: String, user:String, pwd:String) extends org.apache.spark.sql.ForeachWriter[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]{
    val driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
    var connection:java.sql.Connection = _
    var statement:java.sql.Statement = _

    def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long):Boolean = {
        Class.forName(driver)
        connection = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd)
        statement = connection.createStatement
        true
    }

    def process(value: org.apache.spark.sql.Row): Unit = {        
    statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO public.test(col1, col2) " +
                             "VALUES ('" + value(0) + "'," + value(1) + ");")
    }

    def close(errorOrNull:Throwable):Unit = {
        connection.close
    }
}

val url="jdbc:postgresql://<mypostgreserver>:<port>/<mydb>"
val user="<user name>"
val pwd="<pass>"
val writer = new JDBCSink(url, user, pwd)

import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.ProcessingTime

val query=wordCounts
  .writeStream
  .foreach(writer)
  .outputMode("complete")
  .trigger(ProcessingTime("25 seconds"))
  .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

Error message:

```
ERROR StreamExecution: Query [id = ef2e7a4c-0d64-4cad-ad4f-91d349f8575b, runId = a86902e6-d168-49d1-b7e7-084ce503ea68] terminated with error
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:298)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2094)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:924)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:923)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:923)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ForeachSink.addBatch(ForeachSink.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$1.apply$mcV$sp(StreamExecution.scala:503)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:503)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:503)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:262)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:46)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch(StreamExecution.scala:502)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(StreamExecution.scala:255)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:244)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:244)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:262)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:46)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1.apply$mcZ$sp(StreamExecution.scala:244)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches(StreamExecution.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:177)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution
Serialization stack:
        - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution, value: Streaming Query [id = 9b01db99-9120-4047-b779-2e2e0b289f65, runId = e20beefa-146a-4139-96f9-de3d64ce048a] [state = TERMINATED])
        - field (class: $line21.$read$$iw$$iw, name: query, type: interface org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery)
        - object (class $line21.$read$$iw$$iw, $line21.$read$$iw$$iw@24747e0f)
        - field (class: $line21.$read$$iw, name: $iw, type: class $line21.$read$$iw$$iw)
        - object (class $line21.$read$$iw, $line21.$read$$iw@1814ed19)
        - field (class: $line21.$read, name: $iw, type: class $line21.$read$$iw)
        - object (class $line21.$read, $line21.$read@13e62f5d)
        - field (class: $line25.$read$$iw, name: $line21$read, type: class $line21.$read)
        - object (class $line25.$read$$iw, $line25.$read$$iw@14240e5c)
        - field (class: $line25.$read$$iw$$iw, name: $outer, type: class $line25.$read$$iw)
        - object (class $line25.$read$$iw$$iw, $line25.$read$$iw$$iw@11e4c6f5)
        - field (class: $line25.$read$$iw$$iw$JDBCSink, name: $outer, type: class $line25.$read$$iw$$iw)
        - object (class $line25.$read$$iw$$iw$JDBCSink, $line25.$read$$iw$$iw$JDBCSink@6c096c84)
        - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ForeachSink, name: org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$ForeachSink$$writer, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.ForeachWriter)
        - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ForeachSink, org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ForeachSink@6feccb75)
        - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ForeachSink$$anonfun$addBatch$1, name: $outer, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ForeachSink)
        - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ForeachSink$$anonfun$addBatch$1, <function1>)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:295)
        ... 25 more
```

How to make it work?

**SOLUTION**

(Thanks to all, special thaks to @zsxwing for a straightforward solution):

1. Save JDBCSink class to a file.
2. In spark-shell load a class f.eg. using `scala> :load <path_to_a_JDBCSink.scala_file>`
3. Finally `scala> :paste` code without JDBCSink class definition.

Comment: can u please tell how to can i insert data to hdfs or hive after grouping

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just define JDBCSink in a separated file rather than defining it as an inner class which may capture the outer reference.

Comment: @Lukiz can u please tell how to can i insert data to hdfs or hive after grouping

Comment: @BigD I haven't tried to save it to hdfs or hive this way. But except from checking Spark docs, that you have probably done, i'd suggest you to look at kafka with apropriate connector: [link](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-hdfs/index.html#connect-hdfs). First sentence sounds promissing: "The HDFS connector allows you to export data from Kafka topics to HDFS files in a variety of formats and integrates with Hive to make data immediately available for querying with HiveQL." So if you can, add kafka to your processing architecture, Hope that helps. Regards.

Comment: actually my requirement is to fetch data from kafka using spark streaming nad joining data with one of the hive table and write it back to Hive... am not getting data wrote to the hdfs after aggregating .... can you share your thoughts .. @Lukiz

Answer (score 2):

In case somebody encounters this in an interactive workbook, this solution also works:

Instead of saving the `JDBCSink`class to a seperate file, you can also just declare it as a separate package ("Packaged cell") within the same workbook and import that package in the cell where you are using it. Well described here https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/notebooks/package-cells.html

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the offender here is the use of `import spark.implicits._` inside the `JDBCSink` class:

- `JDBCSink` must be serializable
- By adding this import, you make your `JDBCSink` reference the non-serializable `SparkSession` which is then serialized along with it (techincally, `SparkSession extends Serializable`, but it's not meant to be deserialized on the worker nodes)

The good news: you're not using this import, so if you just *remove* it, this should work.