# How to write result of streaming query to multiple database tables?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am using spark structured streaming and reading from Kafka topic. The goal is to write the message to PostgreSQL database multiple tables.

The message schema is:

```
 root
  |-- id: string (nullable = true)
  |-- name: timestamp (nullable = true)
  |-- comment: string (nullable = true)
  |-- map_key_value: map (nullable = true)
    |-- key: string
    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

While writing to one table after dropping map_key_value works with below code:

My write code is:

```
message.writeStream.foreachBatch { (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
    batchDF.write.format("jdbc").option("url", "url")
      .option("user", "username")
      .option("password", "password")
      .option(JDBCOptions.JDBC_TABLE_NAME, "table_1')
      .mode(SaveMode.Append).save();
  }.outputMode(OutputMode.Append()).start().awaitTermination()
```

I want to write the message to two DB tables table 1(id, name, comment) and tables 2 need have the map_key_value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need N streaming queries for N sinks; t1 and t2 both count as a separate sink.

writeStream does not currently write to jdbc so you should use [foreachBatch](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach-and-foreachbatch) operator.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45373795/how-to-write-jdbc-sink-for-spark-structured-streaming-sparkexception-task-not